# How to uninstall pygame from ubuntu?

Tags: updates, python, uninstall

Today I tried to update so I entered sudo apt update through the terminal. However it returned with

> The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/thopiekar/pygame/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

So I tried to update with

> sudo apt update --allow-unauthenticated

However that still didn't work so I decided to uninstall pygame with

> python3 -m pip uninstall pygame --user

Python returned with

> Usage:
> /usr/bin/python3 -m pip uninstall [options]  ...
> /usr/bin/python3 -m pip uninstall [options] -r  ...
> no such option: --user

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to update or uninstall?  How did you install it originally?  Where are you coming up with these commands?

Comment: @Nmath 1. I'm trying to uninstall pygame, i don't really code much 2. I installed it with pip. 3. I just searched each error and tried a solution.

Comment: There are a few problems here. First, `apt update` only updates the *list* of available software. You have to use `apt upgrade` if you actually want to upgrade packages to the current version. Second, your system updates are broken.  See: [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file). But neither of these things have anything to do with uninstalling software installed with pip

Comment: to uninstall most software that you install with `pip install packagename` you need only to use the command `pip uninstall packagename`.  Is there some problem when you use this command?